# How to add elements to a root using org.w3c.Dom

Tags: dom

I am using Org.W3c.dom for generating and parsing XML files in my app.

Here I am stuck because I can not find a way to add more elements to a Root element.

I want to generate Xml as below :

```
<root>
       <siteDesc>abc</siteDesc>
       <respCode>false</respCode>
       <respMsg>Done</respMsg>
  </root>
```

Here is the code which I am using to generate XML File ...

```
private final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Element responseElement = document.createElementNS(NAMESPACE_URI, "root");
responseElement.appendChild("TODO") // Confused Here .. How to append elements with their names
```

Can anyone suggest me, Here In above code .. What are the required changed to add elements to the roor node ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to

1. create a  node and add that to your document (`responseElement`)
2. create further `Elements` and add those to your `responseElement` (again, using `appendChild()`)
3. for each of these, create a `TextNode` and add those to your `Elements`

In the above, the element creation is distinct from the addition to the document.